# Is there a way to get all controllers in an ExtJS 4.0 application

Tags: web-applications, extjs, extjs4

I'm building an app using ExtJS 4.0's new MVC architecture. I'm looking for a way to iterate over all the controllers in the app. below I've put some sample code to give an idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    appFolder: '/App',
    controllers: [
        'HdMenuItemsController'
    ],
    launch: function () {
        //This works:
        this.getController('HdMenuItemsController')

        //I want to do something like this:
        this.controllers.each(myFunction);

        //or this:
        this.getAllControllers().each(myFunction);

        //or this:
        Ext.getControllersForApp(this).each(myFunction);


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

No built in way that I know of (and I am kinda curious why you would need to do this), but you can accomplish this as follows (place this in your `launch()` function as you have in your example):

```
this.controllers.each(function(item, index, length){
    var myController = this.getController(item.id);
    //now do something with myController!

    //OR:
    this.getController(item.id).someFunction();
    //where someFunction() is defined in all of your controllers
});
```